# kernel of certain sheaf morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $C$ be a site, $Set$ be the category of sheaf of sets on $C$, $Ab$ be the category of sheaves of abelian groups on $C$. There is a left adjoint functor $\mathbb{Z}[-]$ to the forgetful functor $Ab \to Set$. More explicitly, it takes $\mathcal{F} \in Set$ to the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U \to \mathbb{Z}[\mathcal{F}(U)]$. Given an $\mathcal{F} \in Ab$, there is a surjection (in $Ab$)  $\mathbb{Z}[\mathcal{F}] \to \mathcal{F}$. How's the kernel look like?

Comment: No, it already fails if $C$ is a point, that is if $Ab$ is the category of usual abelian groups and $Set$ the category of usual sets. Indeed if $\mathbb{Z}[\mathcal{F}]$ is the free group of rank $\operatorname{Card}\mathcal{F}$ so the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}[\mathcal{F}]\to\mathcal{F}$ has rank $\operatorname{Card}\mathcal{F}-\operatorname{rk}\mathcal{F}$ which is usually very big and strictly greater than 1 if $\mathcal{F}$ is not trivial.

Comment: @Roland , you're definite right.  I should've said coproduct of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$. If $\mathcal{C}$ is the etale/fppf site over a fixed scheme , $G$ is a finite abelian group and $\mathcal{F}$ is a locally constant sheaf with fiber $G$, is the above kernel $\oplus_G \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Let the cardinality of $G$ =n. It seems to me the kernel is given by the sheaf: $U \mapsto (\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus n})^{ \pi_0(U)}$, where $\pi_0(U)$ denotes the number of connected components of $U$. So the kernel is really the constant sheaf associated to $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus n}$. Is it correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: But the kernel might not be of constant rank if $\mathcal{F}$ is not of constant cardinality.

Comment: If $\mathcal{F}$ is the constant sheaf associated to G, then it should be of constant cardinality, right? my claim should thus be true?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't take into account your first comment. If $\mathcal{F}$ is constant, then this is true since it holds for the category of sets. It follows that the kernel is locally constant with fiber a free group. In full generality, I am not sure you can conclude anything from this. I will think about it.

Comment: @Roland, surely it'll be interesting to know how the kernel looks like in general. But I'm actually more interested in a few examples of representable sheaves. Namely, if $\mathcal{C}$ is say the big fppf site over $Spec k$ where $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$, I want to understand what the kernel is when $\mathcal{F}= \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$,$\mu_n$ and $\alpha_p$. From the above discussion, it seems clear for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mu_n$ ($n\neq p$). I'm thinking about the cases of $\mu_p$ and $\alpha_p$. What should be the kernel like?